# How do I specify a global HttpWebRequest timeout?

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, tweetinvi

I'm using a twitter library that uses `HttpWebRequest` internally to make requests to the twitter API. For some odd reason, the requests sometimes take a lot of time to complete (~10 minutes).

The `HttpWebRequest` object is not exposed by the library.

Is there any way to specify a global timeout and readwritetimeout for the requests, perhaps via *app.config*?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not currently possible. The constructor of `HttpWebRequest` has this value hardcoded - [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,5126).

Answer (score -1):

That timeout is in milliseconds - so 2000ms = only 2 seconds.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("URL");
req.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timeOut"]);
Req.ReadWriteTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["readWriteTimeout "]);
```

App.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="timeOut" value="200" />
<add key="readWriteTimeout " value="10000" />
</appSettings>
```

Timeout = time spent trying to establish a connection (not including lookup time)

ReadWriteTimeout = time spent trying to read or write data after connection established

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned in the question, I don't have access to the `req` object.

Comment: Since it's impossible in web.config, this answer helps with a workaround. Thanks!